# Howto search all fields with NHibernate Search?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

NHibernate is working fine in my current solution but I would like to do queries that search all fields. How can I do something like

```
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("*", queryText)
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("%", queryText)
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("*:test")
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("%:test")
```

I tried the above but these do not work. I search for quite some time but cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: Ramon, dont forget to mark the right answer! Greetings from Argentina

Answer (score 2):

You have to write:

```
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("Field:{0}", criteria);
```

For example:

```
.CreateFullTextQuery<MyObjectGraph>("Name:{0}", "Ramon");
```